# What are the ranking methods based on preferences?

Tags: ranking, decision-theory

I dont mean some MCDM ranking methods because we have to put the weights for criteria in MCDM. I am wondering is there any ranking method base on the preference input. For example: we have 10 people give their preferences on 3 items I1, I2, I3. The format of the preference will be :

```
 P1: I1<I3<I2... 
 P2: I1<I2<I3
  ...
 P10: I3<I1<I2
```

And the output after applying a ranking method will be

```
 I1<I2<I3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some methods that you can use: [Borda Count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borda_count) and [Condorcet Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_method) are two popular ones.